# Check whether the cursor of a mouse is over a component

Tags: java, button, cursor, components, mouse

I need a function which checks whether the cursor of the mouse is over a component. The components will be a `JButton`, `JTextField`, and a `JLabel`. I have tried the following code

```
@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        boolean noDraw = false;

        if(this.getWidth() > mX && mX > 0){
            if( this.getHeight() > mY && mY > 0){
               components = this.getComponents();
               if( components != null){
                   for(int i = 0; i < components.length; ++i){
                      if( components[i].contains(mX, mY)){
                          noDraw = true;
                          break;
                      }
                   }
               }
               if(noDraw == false )
               {
                   Cicle.draw(g);
               }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: So what have you tried? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @szym05 Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @Dan thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in Java called a `Mouse Listener` which you could use. You add it to the components individually and then when the mouse goes over the component a `MouseEvent` would occur. For Example if you had a `JButton` called `yourComponent` you would add the `Mouse Listener` to the component like so.

```
yourComponent.addMouseListener(new CustomMouseListener());

class CustomMouseListener implements MouseListener
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //Mouse is over component
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            System.out.println("Mouse is over a JButton");
        }

        if (source instanceof JTextField) {
            System.out.println("Mouse is over a JTextField");
        }

        if (source instanceof JLabel) {
            System.out.println("Mouse is over a JLabel");
        }

        Sysem.out.println("Mouse is over "+ e.getComponent().getClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
         //Mouse is not over component
         Sysem.out.println("Mouse is not over "+ e.getComponent().getClass().getName()+" anymore");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

See ["How to write a `Mouse Listener`"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more information on how they work

Comment: A `mouseAdapter` would be much more suitable.

Comment: @user1803551 That is true